# Programmatically determining ClickOnce install mode

Tags: clickonce

We have both online and offline versions of our [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) applications. Is there a way to programmatically determine if a ClickOnce application's install mode was online or offline?

For clarity, I am using the terms "offline" and "online" in the manner they are described in the document *[How to: Specify the ClickOnce Offline or Online Install Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0507x17.aspx)* ([MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)).

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if an application is being run from the web like this:

```
  try {
      if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment == null ||
          ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri == null)
      return false;
  } 
  catch {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
```

This will be true only when you run it from the web, so if you want to access this information later on, persist the value somewhere.